# Javascript create dynamic array with for loop in MVC View

Tags: javascript

I have a status list named **statusList** from controller.

```
@{
    var statusList = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Statuses));
}
```

---

I want to parse it like below. I am using an array something like this in javascript:

```
var options = {
    '0': '',
    '1': 'Pending',
    '2': 'In Progress',
    '3': 'Done'
};
```

When I write this hardcoded for testing, it works as intented. But when I try to populate it in for loop like this:

```
var options = [];

for (var i = 0; i < statusList.length; i++) {
    var id = statusList[i]["Id"];
    var name = statusList[i]["Status"];

    options.push({id : name});
}
```

This write [object Object] to select input. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: try like this var statusList = JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.Statuses);

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. id and name are dynamic so you have to put them in brackets when you push it to the array. The way you have it  Now your array will looks like :    `[{id : name},{id : name}]`. Also the reason you are seeing `[Object Object]` is because you have to stringify your results in order to see whats inside.

```
var options = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < statusList.length; i++) {
            var id = statusList[i].id;
            var name = statusList[i].status;

            options.push({[id] : [name]});
        }

console.log(JSON.stringify(options))
```